# Snippet editor for touch devices can be opened if you show perseverance

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, touch-screen

Opening a code snippet editor via the button from the toolbar cannot be used on touch screen devices like my iPad, i.e. I see the following notice:

> [image: don’t touch code snippet on touch devices]

But occasionally tapping code snippet button several times I managed to open it:

> [image: but I did a touch]

So here’s some kind of unstable bug in touch screen device detection algorithm. I don’t understand why to restrict code snippet for only untouchable (?) devices either.

Also, in some cases detection is wrong when device (a laptop) has not only touch screen, but also a keyboard: [Добавление фрагмента кода (JS/HTML/CSS) на ноутбуках с сенсорным экраном](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5508/176217)