# Mobile experience of the website not standardized, very impractical to use and add code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web, responsive-design

Title says it all. When writing an answer on a mobile device the options for  adding snippets do not appear at all in any way in the slightest, there's no way I can either add, or even view, a code snippet in the mobile browser, the best I can do it three `s manually and write the code, but when then there's no way to add a tab or indent, in desktop one can copy code from test editor, select it, and format it, this option is also not available in mobile, how am I supposed to write answers that require code?

Basically a simple mobile code editor should at least be added, that inserts a tab character on request, and either results in a snippet or even just basic formatted code would be fantastical, or at the very very least the ability to select a block of pasted text and indent it, like it works on desktop, since there's no way to do that currently

This is not necessarily a question about the mobile site, it's about the mobile exp experience, regardless of what site it's on, even in the desktop version there is no way at all to add a tab character, also if the desktop version is preferred then it should automatically redirect to that and possibly just fix the css so one doesn't have to manually zoom in, either make the desktop version for mobile the new standard and completely remove the old mobile site, or fix the mobile site, but either way, mobile*users* need a tab key

A simple reason why the current desktop site doesn't work is because of the small buttons, if the desktop site should be the new normal, then the button sizes should simply be increased, here are a couple screenshots demonstrating the problem:

[image]

[image]

Notice how small the buttons and links are. If one remains zoomed out then one is not able to focus on the correct button, if one zooms I'm to click on the button that ruins the mobile flow anyways, if people are expected to use the desktop site on mobile then there buttons should be bigger, and either way a tab key should be added

The size of the buttons themselves isn't the only problem, there are several inconsistencies in the css in other areas when viewing the desktop site on mobile, including the comments of the original user being smaller:

[image]

As well as the text input for editing and inserting answers (two pictures up) being too small to select and scroll through, the css of that when viewing on a mobile phone should also be made bigger, it mobile users should be expected to view the desktop version, but if you ask me in order for the mobile site to work at least temporarily for now is to add a simple tab button or code format button we the very least, if the old mobile site isn't expected to be used, then it should be completely removed, but if it's still there it should be at least minimally usable

Also, further indications that the snippet editor doesn't work on mobile:

[image]

This question kept being associated with another one that was left for dust, but the other one only dealt with a code button, but this one deals with the entire mobile experience, including the desktop site, that is not dealt with in the other one, specifically:
*The small buttons and small input size for questions on the desktop site* that is not addressed at all in any way whatsoever in the slightest in the other question, the indentation is part of it but mainly just being able to use it, as well as sniper support not being mentioned at in any way whatever in the slightest in the other question

While I do agree with the other question, and mention part of it here, there are still several differences between them. For example, the main/only thing the OP of the other question is asking is :

[Can we have a "format code" button in the mobile theme?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101774/can-we-have-a-format-code-button-in-the-mobile-theme)

It's very difficult to post code on Stack Overflow using the mobile theme on an iDevice. I've tried indenting the code by 4 spaces, but I'm still getting an error that the code is not formatted correctly. Not to mention the fact that it's extremely tedious to do this by hand.

It would be much easier if we could just select all of the code and click a single button to format it automatically, much like we can already do using the full site. This seems like an important feature for Stack Overflow, even on the mobile theme. If we're going to be able to ask questions, we should be able to post snippets of code that accompany those questions

---

While the features of this question include:

Bigger buttons on the desktop site when accessed on mobile

Bigger input box for entering code into to allow for easier scrolling

Fixed implementations of snippet editing (besides for formatting, specifically snippet editing)

A potential tab key button, similar to how code editor apps work, though this is not as necessary as the other things

Fixed css inconsistencies with some comments /links appearing tiny while others appearing bigger

A fixed redirection, straight to the newly improved desktop (for mobile) site, without going to the ten year old unmaintained "mobile" site that is anyways discouraged from working with indenting etc

Comment: There are multiple mobile experiences, and it would be nice if you [edit] this question to indicate which one you're using, and add the appropriate tag: the mobile site ([tag:mobile-web]), the full site accessed through a mobile browser ([tag:responsive-design]), or the mobile apps ([tag:ios-app] or [tag:android-app]).

Comment: @sonic not sure what you're referring to, I am talking about the website as it is accessed by a mobile phone, which generally means the mobile site unless one activated desktop mode, in which case it wouldn't be a question about mobile devices anymore

Comment: @somic also the app link you posted reads ": THE APP IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED. This tag is to be used for the official Stack Exchange application only. The application is no longer available in the Google Play store, for Android 4.1 and up. "

Comment: Okay, so you're using the mobile site. There are users who use one of the other experiences, including the mobile apps, which still work for users who installed them before they were removed, who don't specify their experience in the question, and get confused when we tell them how to use the mobile website. That's why I'd asked you to make this more clear. Thanks for doing that.

Comment: @Sonic ok cool.

Comment: Anyway, the sad thing is that the mobile site hasn't been maintained in nearly a decade, and this has previously been requested, but never resolved: [Can we have a "format code" button in the mobile theme?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101774/can-we-have-a-format-code-button-in-the-mobile-theme). As Stack Exchange is pushing all mobile users to use the full site (which is responsive), the mobile site is no longer receiving feature updates.

Comment: @sonic it partly touches on some aspects of this question, but doesn't address snippets, or the possibility of a simple tab key, and it's also not answered

Comment: @somic how can a mobile user use the full site without a desktop device? Should everyone just request desktop? It so then why isn't that activated by default?

Comment: Yeah, I expect this redirect to be removed eventually; it seems that part of the system was never touched yet. Anyway, things have gotten a bit better for mobile site users due to support for \`\`\`  code fences, which mean that you only need to place those characters in a line at the beginning and the end of a code block, fairly easy to do on a mobile device. Previously, it was necessary to go through and put four spaces at the beginning of *every* line, and considering that most mobile keyboards would replace two spaces with `. `, that was extremely tedious.

Comment: @sonic yes I also use the `s so the time, but they still don't indent, a simple "tab" button, either both on the desktop and mobile, or only in the mobile site, would help tremendously

Comment: "even in the desktop version there is no way at all to add a tab character"...that's more an issue with your phone's keyboard, not with the Stack Exchange editor. I imagine that there must be at least one alternate keyboard you can install that does support tab characters.

Comment: @sonic no that's not an issue with the keyboard, almost all standard keyboards that come with mobile devices don't have a tab key, if users are expected to use the website at all with a mobile phone, which includes writing answers, which includes writing code, they should be given the basic tools to easily do that. Technically the bold and italics buttons aren't necessary for anyone, as they can just type `*` characters, similarly code indentation isn't necessary at all for anyone, the code still works the same, but it's all about accessibility and ease of use

Comment: @rob thanks, added it

Comment: Some bug [reports say](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338932/touch-laptop-the-snippet-editor-does-not-support-touch-devices#comment675770_348096) that touchscreens can't be used and hacks break, while (frustratingly) [other reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303986/282094) say that the Snippet Editor ***sometimes*** works just fine; after multiple attempts. There's [more than one site](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3295/122794) offering this complaint and solutions.

Comment: @sonic how in the world if this a duplicate, the other question doesn't address the small buttons on the desktop site, nor the snippets, and not even the tab key suggestion , it only has one small detail in common

Comment: @rob can't believe these communist overlords are trying to shut us down, kinda makes me want to put on some ddos attacks to EE, they've gotta have a limit on bandwidth eventually

Comment: Much of the duplicate votes came in back from earlier revisions of this question. I'm not sure why people continued to vote even after you edited it. I've voted to reopen it, but it would be nice if you linked to that question and explained why this isn't a duplicate so others are more inclined to vote to reopen as well.

Comment: Agree it's not duplicate, reopened. However, I see only rant. OK, so the mobile experience is terrible. What you suggest to improve?

Comment: @shadow  added a summary of the features at bottom

Comment: OK, fair enough, it's all about same thing. But please add this on **top**, with TL;DR so that people won't have to scroll way down.

Comment: @shadow what should I add to the top exactly

Comment: It looks like you are using chrome on a mobile device. The site shouldn't look like it does in your screenshot. For me it is not like that, the text and buttons are larger. Can you check and make sure you have "Desktop site" turned off? Here is an answer I provided for a similar question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345595/299995

Comment: @kodos yes there's definitely with Delta mode off